# Can anyone give me a short code example in c using opengl where clicking in two different squares changes their color?

Tags: c, opengl

Can anyone give me a short code example in c using opengl where clicking in two different squares changes their color? I'm particularly interested in knowing how to detect that a mouse click has happened to a particular primitive.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [GL selection-mode example](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/triselect.c)

```
/* Copyright (c) Mark J. Kilgard, 1994. */

/**
* (c) Copyright 1993, Silicon Graphics, Inc.
* ALL RIGHTS RESERVED 
* Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software for 
* any purpose and without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
* copyright notice appear in all copies and that both the copyright notice
* and this permission notice appear in supporting documentation, and that 
* the name of Silicon Graphics, Inc. not be used in advertising
* or publicity pertaining to distribution of the software without specific,
* written prior permission. 
*
* THE MATERIAL EMBODIED ON THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED TO YOU "AS-IS"
* AND WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS, IMPLIED OR OTHERWISE,
* INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, ANY WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY OR
* FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  IN NO EVENT SHALL SILICON
* GRAPHICS, INC.  BE LIABLE TO YOU OR ANYONE ELSE FOR ANY DIRECT,
* SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL, INDIRECT OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OF ANY
* KIND, OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION,
* LOSS OF PROFIT, LOSS OF USE, SAVINGS OR REVENUE, OR THE CLAIMS OF
* THIRD PARTIES, WHETHER OR NOT SILICON GRAPHICS, INC.  HAS BEEN
* ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH LOSS, HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON
* ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
* POSSESSION, USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
* 
* US Government Users Restricted Rights 
* Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is subject to
* restrictions set forth in FAR 52.227.19(c)(2) or subparagraph
* (c)(1)(ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer Software
* clause at DFARS 252.227-7013 and/or in similar or successor
* clauses in the FAR or the DOD or NASA FAR Supplement.
* Unpublished-- rights reserved under the copyright laws of the
* United States.  Contractor/manufacturer is Silicon Graphics,
* Inc., 2011 N.  Shoreline Blvd., Mountain View, CA 94039-7311.
*
* OpenGL(TM) is a trademark of Silicon Graphics, Inc.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define MAXOBJS 10000
#define MAXSELECT 100
#define MAXFEED 300
#define SOLID 1
#define LINE 2
#define POINT 3

GLint windW = 300, windH = 300;

GLuint selectBuf[MAXSELECT];
GLfloat feedBuf[MAXFEED];
GLint vp[4];
float zRotation = 90.0;
float zoom = 1.0;
GLint objectCount;
GLint numObjects;
struct object {
    float v1[2];
    float v2[2];
    float v3[2];
    float color[3];
} objects[MAXOBJS];
GLenum linePoly = GL_FALSE;

static void InitObjects(GLint num)
{
    GLint i;
    float x, y;

    if (num > MAXOBJS) {
        num = MAXOBJS;
    }
    if (num < 1) {
        num = 1;
    }
    objectCount = num;

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        x = (rand() % 300) - 150;
        y = (rand() % 300) - 150;

        objects[i].v1[0] = x + (rand() % 50) - 25;
        objects[i].v2[0] = x + (rand() % 50) - 25;
        objects[i].v3[0] = x + (rand() % 50) - 25;
        objects[i].v1[1] = y + (rand() % 50) - 25;
        objects[i].v2[1] = y + (rand() % 50) - 25;
        objects[i].v3[1] = y + (rand() % 50) - 25;
        objects[i].color[0] = ((rand() % 100) + 50) / 150.0;
        objects[i].color[1] = ((rand() % 100) + 50) / 150.0;
        objects[i].color[2] = ((rand() % 100) + 50) / 150.0;
    }
}

static void Init(void)
{
    numObjects = 10;
    InitObjects(numObjects);
}

static void Reshape(int width, int height)
{
    windW = width;
    windH = height;
    glViewport(0, 0, windW, windH);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vp);
}

static void Render(GLenum mode)
{
    GLint i;

    for (i = 0; i < objectCount; i++) {
        if (mode == GL_SELECT) {
            glLoadName(i);
        }
        glColor3fv(objects[i].color);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2fv(objects[i].v1);
        glVertex2fv(objects[i].v2);
        glVertex2fv(objects[i].v3);
        glEnd();
    }
}

static GLint DoSelect(GLint x, GLint y)
{
    GLint hits;

    glSelectBuffer(MAXSELECT, selectBuf);
    glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);
    glInitNames();
    glPushName(~0);

    glPushMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPickMatrix(x, windH - y, 4, 4, vp);
    gluOrtho2D(-175, 175, -175, 175);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glScalef(zoom, zoom, zoom);
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0, 0, 1);

    Render(GL_SELECT);

    glPopMatrix();

    hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);
    if (hits <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return selectBuf[(hits - 1) * 4 + 3];
}

static void RecolorTri(GLint h)
{
    objects[h].color[0] = ((rand() % 100) + 50) / 150.0;
    objects[h].color[1] = ((rand() % 100) + 50) / 150.0;
    objects[h].color[2] = ((rand() % 100) + 50) / 150.0;
}

static void DeleteTri(GLint h)
{
    objects[h] = objects[objectCount - 1];
    objectCount--;
}

static void GrowTri(GLint h)
{
    float v[2];
    float *oldV;
    GLint i;

    v[0] = objects[h].v1[0] + objects[h].v2[0] + objects[h].v3[0];
    v[1] = objects[h].v1[1] + objects[h].v2[1] + objects[h].v3[1];
    v[0] /= 3;
    v[1] /= 3;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        switch (i) {
case 0:
    oldV = objects[h].v1;
    break;
case 1:
    oldV = objects[h].v2;
    break;
case 2:
    oldV = objects[h].v3;
    break;
        }
        oldV[0] = 1.5 * (oldV[0] - v[0]) + v[0];
        oldV[1] = 1.5 * (oldV[1] - v[1]) + v[1];
    }
}

static void Mouse(int button, int state, int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    GLint hit;

    if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        hit = DoSelect((GLint) mouseX, (GLint) mouseY);
        if (hit != -1) {
            if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
                RecolorTri(hit);
            } else if (button == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON) {
                GrowTri(hit);
            } else if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) {
                DeleteTri(hit);
            }
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
    }
}

static void Draw(void)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-175, 175, -175, 175);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glScalef(zoom, zoom, zoom);
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0, 0, 1);
    Render(GL_RENDER);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void DumpFeedbackVert(GLint * i, GLint n)
{
    GLint index;

    index = *i;
    if (index + 7 > n) {
        *i = n;
        printf("  ???\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("  (%g %g %g), color = (%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f)\n",
        feedBuf[index],
        feedBuf[index + 1],
        feedBuf[index + 2],
        feedBuf[index + 3],
        feedBuf[index + 4],
        feedBuf[index + 5]);
    index += 7;
    *i = index;
}

static void DrawFeedback(GLint n)
{
    GLint i;
    GLint verts;

    printf("Feedback results (%d floats):\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        switch ((GLint) feedBuf[i]) {
case GL_POLYGON_TOKEN:
    printf("Polygon");
    i++;
    if (i < n) {
        verts = (GLint) feedBuf[i];
        i++;
        printf(": %d vertices", verts);
    } else {
        verts = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
    while (verts) {
        DumpFeedbackVert(&i, n);
        verts--;
    }
    i--;
    break;
case GL_LINE_TOKEN:
    printf("Line:\n");
    i++;
    DumpFeedbackVert(&i, n);
    DumpFeedbackVert(&i, n);
    i--;
    break;
case GL_LINE_RESET_TOKEN:
    printf("Line Reset:\n");
    i++;
    DumpFeedbackVert(&i, n);
    DumpFeedbackVert(&i, n);
    i--;
    break;
default:
    printf("%9.2f\n", feedBuf[i]);
    break;
        }
    }
    if (i == MAXFEED) {
        printf("...\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static void DoFeedback(void)
{
    GLint x;

    glFeedbackBuffer(MAXFEED, GL_3D_COLOR, feedBuf);
    (void) glRenderMode(GL_FEEDBACK);

    glPushMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-175, 175, -175, 175);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glScalef(zoom, zoom, zoom);
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0, 0, 1);

    Render(GL_FEEDBACK);

    glPopMatrix();

    x = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);
    if (x == -1) {
        x = MAXFEED;
    }
    DrawFeedback((GLint) x);
}

static void Key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{

    switch (key) {
case 'z':
    zoom /= 0.75;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    break;
case 'Z':
    zoom *= 0.75;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    break;
case 'f':
    DoFeedback();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    break;
case 'l':
    linePoly = !linePoly;
    if (linePoly) {
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    } else {
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    break;
case 27:
    exit(0);
    }
}

static void SpecialKey(int key, int x, int y)
{

    switch (key) {
case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
    zRotation += 0.5;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    break;
case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
    zRotation -= 0.5;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("Select Test");
    Init();
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Key);
    glutSpecialFunc(SpecialKey);
    glutMouseFunc(Mouse);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;             /* ANSI C requires main to return int. */
}
```

That program is a part of [some other GLUT examples](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html).

The GL selection buffer is old and busted though, you're probably better off using color-readback selection or some CPU-side "ray casting" system that integrates with your geometry representation.

Comment: This is not an appropriate answer; it's just a link with the text 'Here you go." It would be better if you could paraphrase the relevant contents of the linked page here and use the link only for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on OpenGL's [selection](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/sig99/advanced99/notes/node35.html) feature. That is the classical way of doing it, and should work well for at least small amount of object (which sounds right for your question).

Comment: but could you post a small example of how it works? I don't understand the mechanisms involved to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete example, but there's also a section on the [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/) on [Picking and Selection](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm) which should be noted.